# Microsoft Store Add-Ons bulk sale

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, add-on

I have an app in the microsoft store and store-managed add-ons are available for it.
I wanted to offer my customers to buy the store-managed consumable for a reduced price, if they buy more. e.g. if it was gold, 1 coin would cost $5 and 10 coins $40.

Is there an other way to achieve this than using developer-managed consumables?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Windows Dev Center provide feature for *Sale pricing*, please check [Put apps and add-ons on sale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/put-apps-and-add-ons-on-sale#scheduling-a-sale).During the time period that your product is on sale, customers will be able to purchase it at the lower price during the time period that you have selected.

Otherwise, you may try to create several different add-ons for different prices.